# Django-admin createsuperuser does not work

Tags: django

The Django documentation says syncdb is deprecated and replaced by migrate.  But for a fresh install of Django 1.8, if I run python manage.py migrate and then django-admin createsuperuser, I get an error of:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

But if I run python manage.py syncdb, it gives me a warning about deprecation BUT at the same time prompts me to create a super user, which completed OK.  So is there a way that I should use to create superuser without syncdb?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found that this only happens when I run django-admin createsuperuser, whereas python manage.py createsuperuser will run without complaint

Comment: That's because manage.py is basically the same as django-admin.py except that manage.py file sets DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE to point to your project's settings.py file. You can see this if you compare the django-admin.py source with your locally-generated manage.py.